# Don't render any view by default - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a container `div` with some static HTML. I don't want my react router to do anything if default location is `/`. It expects a default view which I don't have. Is there an easy solution.

I tried this but it doesn't work with back/forward browser button?

```
var initApp = function() { 
    Router.run(routes,  function(Handler) { 

        if(Router.HashLocation.getCurrentPath() !== '/') {
           React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('top-container'));  
        }   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems hacky to suggest - but have you tried passing a mocked component (not inheriting from React.Component) with a no-op `render: function() {}`? Otherwise, I think React will replace your wrapper's innerHTML.

On the other hand - are you rendering server-side? If so, the output of a "dumb" component handler for '/' which prints the same markup as your container currently holds, would quite literally be static HTML anyway, despite being rendered by React.